# GZip Paginated JSON Response

Tags: node.js, compression, zlib

I have a paginated request that gives me a list of objects, which I later concat to get the full list of objects.

If I attempt to JSON.stringify this, it fails for large objects with range error. I was looking for a way to `zlib.gzip` to handle large JSON objects.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing `stream-json` it will solve your problem, It's a great wrapper around streams and parsing a JSON.

```
//require the modules stream-json
const StreamArray = require('stream-json/utils/StreamArray');
// require fs if your using a file
const fs = require('fs');
const zlib = require('zlib');
// Create an instance of StreamArray
const streamArray = StreamArray.make();
fs.createReadStream('./YOUR_FILE.json.gz')
.pipe(zlib.createUnzip()) // Unzip
.pipe(streamArray.input); //Read the stream
//here you can do whatever you want with the stream, 
//you can stream it to response. 
streamArray.output.pipe(process.stdout);
```

In the example, I'm using a JSON (file) but you can use a collection and pass it to the stream.

Hope that's help.